# Find all positives integers $n$ such that $n^3+1$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

A solution as follows:

$n^3+1=x^2$

$n^3=x^2-1$

$n^3=(x-1)(x+1)$

$x-1=(x+1)^2~~or~~x+1=(x-1)^2$

$x^2+x+2=0~~or~~x^2-3x=0$

$x(x-3)=0$

$x=0~~or~~x=3~~\Longrightarrow~~n=2$

Does it cover all possible solutions? How to prove that 2 is the only which solves the problem.

Comment: Ever heard of **Catalan’s Conjecture** (or **Mihăilescu's theorem**)? I think it will be useful for you to know. If you are interested, go here $\longrightarrow$ https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Us-__MukH9I and if you want to know some extra history on the topic, go here $\longrightarrow$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: Supposedly the case of squares and cubes is significantly easier than the general Catalan problem. [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-01/S0273-0979-03-00993-5/S0273-0979-03-00993-5.pdf) is a reference for the case of squares and cubes.

Comment: @lulu hahah I know. That’s why it’s a well-known problem. But I thought maybe the OP would be interested :)

Comment: @user477343  Oh, absolutely.

Comment: But hang on — why can’t $n = 0$?

Comment: @user477343 $n$ is stated to be positive (title)

Comment: @imranfat oh **faceslap**

Comment: Thank you guys so much

Comment: Wow..... I must say, this problem came to me much harder than as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: see that $m^2=n^3+1$ gives $(m-1)(m+1)=n^3$. What factors can $m-1$ and $m+1$ have in common? How can their product be a perfect cube?

Comment: Ah, that works for $m^3+1$.   Can you see a similar trick of $m^3-1$?

Comment: What if $n$ is even?

Comment: Do a case split for when $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: What do you do in that case?

Comment: @lulu $m^3 - 1$ factorizes over the Eisenstein integers. You could then do a similar argument to vrugt's, but with the same problem that the resulting argument is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use that $n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$ so $n+1=n^2-n+1$.
As @Arthur pointed out, it's possible that both factors are not equal. Let's say $n+1=km^2$ and $n^2-n+1=k$. Then we have $n=km^2-1$, $n^2-n+1=k^2m^4-2km^2+1-km^2+1+1=k^2m^4-3km^2+3=k$ or $km^2(km^2-3)=k-3$. The last equation does not have a solution for positive $k>1$, $m>1$ as $km^2-3>k-3$

Comment: Just because $a\cdot b$ is a square, that doesn't mean $a = b$. Take $9\cdot 4$, for instance.

Comment: @Arthur: but $n^2-n+1$ is not a perfect square

Comment: What is implied by "so..."?

Comment: Then take $18\cdot 2$. My point still stands.

Comment: @Arthur: Do you have any example other than 2? Honestly, I can't find another. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example of what? That $a\neq b$ but $a\cdot b$ is a square? $a=1$ and $b$ being a square number larger than $1$ always works, and for _any square number other than the square of a prime_, you can find other examples. I gave you two examples for $a\cdot b=6^2$, but I can give you another: $3\cdot 12$. For $8^2$ we have $16\cdot4$, and for $12^2$ there are _many_ possibilities, including $9\cdot 16, 18\cdot 8$ and $6\cdot24$.